# Warning message when linking access 2007 database with MySql

Tags: mysql, odbc, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 database which I have copied to MySql using access. Since there are some users who will be still using access 2007 I intended to link Access 2007 to MyAql. What it means is an update to either database witll be shown on both databases.

However when I try to Link these two using Access 2007 I get this warning shown below.

[image]

I ignored the warning shown on the image by clicking ok. When I try to update MySql database no updates are happening and nothing is transferred to the Access 2007 database and vice versa.

Comment: Did you try to log on to windows as administrator? BTW that message is unreadable on my pc, which has a big enough screen. Some people use Stackoverflow from devices with much smaller screens. A readable error message is important.

Comment: @Remou the warning reads: You are logged on with non-Admistrative privileges. System DSNs could not be created or modified. I am using access 2007 on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: I viewed your question in edit mode and copied the image reference to another tab in order to see the error message, but I doubt that everyone will do that. My comment regarding logging on as administrator was made having read the error.

Comment: @Remou I am logged as an adminstrator in my pc. I thought I must run ms-access as adminstrator but realized I am logged as one and there is no option for that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222486/how-can-i-connect-to-a-system-odbc-connection-is-access-2010-on-windows-7/12258439#12258439 It may be a 64/32 bit issue, but I am guessing.

Comment: @Remou That link gave me an idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Remou I notice my original table is still unchanged but a copy was created and named table11. I still want the original table synchronised.

Comment: I am fairly sure that table11 is just the local name and that it refers to the same table as the original. You can check this by looking at `?currentdb.TableDefs("table11").SourceTableName` in the immediate window.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16292/discussion-between-sithelo-and-remou)